# Wordpress with multiple loops while displaying posts per categories, can I make it faster?

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, optimization

So I am using wordpress and a custom theme. In the landing page I want to display posts per categories.

Example: supose I have three categories cats, dogs, donkeys . then on my landing page I would have something like :

- Latest 10 cats
- Latest 10 dogs
- Latest 10 donkeys

To do that I ended up doing three loops (and maybe more with more categories), So basically I ended up writing something like this :

```
  <?php $posts = query_posts( array ( 'category_name' => 'cats', 'order' => 'ASC', 'posts_per_page' => 10 ) );?>
  <h1>my cats</h1>
  <?php
  foreach ($posts as $post) :
    if ($post):
   ?>
   <!-- displaying info not so important -->
   <div class="some_wrapper">
     <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
     <img <?php $turl = get_the_post_thumbnail_url(); echo ($turl !== false) ? 'src="' . $turl . '"' : 'src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/10/800/600.jpg"'; ?> alt=""/>
     <span><?php   echo get_the_title(); ?></span></a>
   </div>
  <?php endif;endforeach; ?>

  <?php $posts = query_posts( array ( 'category_name' => 'dogs', 'order' => 'ASC', 'posts_per_page' => 10 ) );?>
  <h1>my dogs</h1>
  <?php
  foreach ($posts as $post) :
    if ($post):
   ?>

   <!-- displaying info not so important -->
   <div class="some_wrapper">
     <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
     <img <?php $turl = get_the_post_thumbnail_url(); echo ($turl !== false) ? 'src="' . $turl . '"' : 'src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/10/800/600.jpg"'; ?> alt=""/>
     <span><?php   echo get_the_title(); ?></span></a>
   </div>
  <?php endif;endforeach; ?>

  <?php $posts = query_posts( array ( 'category_name' => 'donkeys', 'order' => 'ASC', 'posts_per_page' => 10 ) );?>
  <h1>my donkeys</h1>
  <?php
  foreach ($posts as $post) :
    if ($post):
   ?>
   <!-- displaying info not so important -->
   <div class="some_wrapper">
     <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
     <img <?php $turl = get_the_post_thumbnail_url(); echo ($turl !== false) ? 'src="' . $turl . '"' : 'src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/10/800/600.jpg"'; ?> alt=""/>
     <span><?php   echo get_the_title(); ?></span></a>
   </div>
  <?php endif;endforeach; ?>
```

Things are working but,
**Can I make it faster, like maybe doing One Loop instead of 3 (or more if u have more categories)** or using another way to loop?

Comment: How slow is it? Is your query slow or is your looping slow?

Comment: Hey @caiovisk I would say with 20 categories or more it can be slow enough to think about making it faster, So Any idea?

Comment: With all those functions in the wordpress codex maybe there's a cooler way the make the loops ?

Comment: There is, but you need to start reading the documentation and understand how the Wordpress works, start learning from codex what [query_posts()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/) function does, then you will see you are using the wrong approach... Also there is plenty of info on this website also see: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50761/when-to-use-wp-query-query-posts-and-pre-get-posts

Comment: @caiovisk you say I am using a wrong Approach and I don't question your wisdom so what is wrong with my approach ?

Comment: I can see that you have read none of the links I've referred, the first paragraph from CODEX about `query_post()` says: "Note: This function will completely override the main query and isn’t intended for use by plugins or themes. Its overly-simplistic approach to modifying the main query can be problematic and should be avoided wherever possible. In most cases, there are better, more performant options for modifying the main query such as via the ‘pre_get_posts’ action within WP_Query."

Comment: @caiovisk Interesting , let's suppose we use your selected pre_get_posts Approach and we Add a filter to Alter the main Query how do I do that to have the same results as the ones that I get from my code above?

Comment: The approach should be using `WP_Query` or `get_posts()` not `query_post()`... Just my opnion, you can build yours...

Comment: @caiovisk I tried using get_posts with specific args but I couldn't get the posts per categories and/or  do multiple loops to get all the cats then the dogs then the donkeys as I mentionned in the example. So I was thinking the query_post was the only solution that is why I wrote everything using query_post. So you seem to think it is possible by adding a filter on top. I guess I will recheck it maybe I did something wrong or I am missing something. Thanks again for your comments.